# Insertar en base de datos sql recibiendo un objeto en Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Necesito crear un método que reciba un objeto y que inserte en una base de datos los datos de ese objeto.
No se como puedo establecer los valores puesto que no conocería ni el tipo de dato que recibe la tabla ni los del atributo objeto.
Mi primera idea fue pasar directamente el objeto :

```
public static void insert(Object obj) {
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
        String sql = MyHibernateSQL.insertSQL(clazz);
        pstm = JdbcUtil.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.setObject(1, obj);
        pstm.executeUpdate();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static String insertSQL(Class<?> clazz) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + obtenerNombreTabla(clazz);
        sql += " (" + obtenerField(clazz) + ")";
        sql += " VALUES (" + obtenerCantidadValores(clazz) + ")";
        return sql;
```

Aparte de ese pstm.setObject() que no tuve muchas esperanzas en el, intente varias cosas más pero ninguna funcionaba y por mas que estuve buscando no encontre ninguna solución.

Answer (score 0):

Es una mala práctica hacer un solo ínstert para todos tipo de objetos.
Pero existe un método
Objet instanceof nombreClase.
De esa forma sabes que tipo de datos tiene ese objeto y que tipo de insert necesitas hacer